# How to loop a group of view in a activity?

Tags: android

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLabel1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvValue1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I want to loop this group of views in a activity(in java). Also i need to set different text for each textview. I think there might ways to do this. Creating multiple textview in layout is not good solution for this problem. Please help me figure out this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) with a custom [`Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html). The first one displays a list of similar items. The second one fills this list according to a list of objects.

So first, put these views into a XML file named *listview_row.xlm*:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLabel1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvValue1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

It will be the layout used as template for each item.

Then create an object to represent an `Item` which will contain the label and the value:

```
public class Item {
    private String label;
    private String value;

    public Item(String label, String value) {
        this.label = label;
        this.value = value;
    }

   /* Getters and Setters */
}
```

Now, you have to create a custom `Adapter`:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private List<Item> items;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    /* This method creates the items. It basically set TextViews' texts based
       on the list of items given */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);

        TextView label = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvLabel1);
        TextView value = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvValue1);

        Item current = items.get(position);

        label.setText(current.getLabel());
        value.setText(current.getValue());

        return v;
    }
}
```

Then, put this in your main layout:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And finally, in your main activity, create the following method and call it at the end of the `onCreate` method:

```
public void setUpListView() {
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    items.add(new Item("1", "value1"));
    items.add(new Item("2", "value2"));

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_row, items);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**EDIT:**

To remove the space between each item, you have to add these properties in the definition of your `ListView` in the XML file:

```
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

Comment: Why a light line is shown after every list item . [Image](http://imgur.com/S2p9drv)

Comment: This is like this by default. You can remove it by using `android:divider="@null"` and `android:dividerHeight="0dp"`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your textview, view, textview into a parent layout (such as LinearLayout).
Then:

```
LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourLayout);
        for (int j = 0; j < parentLayout.getChildCount(); j++) {
            View v = parentLayout.getChildAt(j);

            //check and convert to comfortable view
            //update text
            //...

        }
```